# Gradle with Flavors configuration

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I read a lot of posts here e couldn't find a way to do it, what i want is define the "res" for debug per flavor, like:

```
+ src
+ main
    + java 
    + res
+ flavor1
    + release
        + res
    + debug
        + res
+ flavor2
    + release
        + res
    + debug
        + res
```

the reason is that I have ic_launcher to each buildTypes , and each flavor has your own ic_launcher, so I need to have de release and debug ic_launcher per flavor.

is that possible?

Comment: Have you tried it this way? It's been a while, but it seems correct to me. Check this article http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_Studio_Gradle_Build_Variants_Example

Comment: @KubaSpatny i've tried and it daesn't work, that whai the android studio don't even find any flavor resource, only the main

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible with the following namings:

- flavor1Release
- flavor1Debug
- flavor2Release
- flavor2Debug

Put in every directory a result folder and your specific launcher icon. Then you can switch the build type and the system will select the correct one

Comment: That way I would be creating 4 flavors, exactly what I'm tying to avoid

Comment: You wouldn't be creating 4 flavors. These folder are for combinations of flavor1 and flavor2 with build types debug and release. It does exactly what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thats correcz @kevinpelgrims . I listed the folder names foe the resources. They're a combination of the build type and product flavor with camel case

Comment: Now I understand what you mean @Mann , that make sense, i'll try it today and let you know, thanks